Largest number of ones in an unfriendly matrix
This is about n by n binary matrices. Call a pair of rows unfriendly if the Hamming distance between the two rows is larger than the number ones they have in common positions. Let us call a matrix unfriendly if all pairs of rows are unfriendly.
The identity matrix is, for example, unfriendly and the all ones matrix is friendly.
The matrix:
1 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 1

is also unfriendly.
What is the largest number of ones an n by n unfriendly binary matrix can have?
EDIT
Let $f(n)$ be the largest  number of ones an n by n unfriendly binary matrix can have.  Following the figures given by @RobPratt, we get $n^2/f(n) = 2, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{16}{9}, \frac{25}{13}, \frac{12}{7}, \frac{7}{4}, \frac{8}{5}, \frac{27}{16}, \frac{50}{29}$ for $n = 2, \dots, 10$. What does this converge to as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
To have something concrete to aim for, here is a conjecture:
Conjecture
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^2} = \frac{2}{3}$$

What have you tried so far?

Here is an argument showing that $f(n)\geq\frac23n^2-o(n^2)$, following the heuristic given in Mathieu Rundström's answer. Along with that answer, this constitutes a proof that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^2}=\frac23.$$
Let $\varepsilon\in(0,0.01)$ be a parameter decaying slowly to zero as $n\to\infty$. Choose each entry of our matrix to be $1$ with probability $p:=2/3-\varepsilon$ and $0$ otherwise. Let the rows be $v_1,\ldots,v_n$.
Two things can go wrong: there can be a pair of unfriendly rows, or there can be very few ones. We deal with these each in turn.
Fix some $i\neq j$. The probability that rows $i$ and $j$ are unfriendly is the probability that $v_i+v_j$ contains more ones than twos. Each entry of $v_i+v_j$ is zero with probability $(1-p)^2$, one with probability $2p(1-p)$, and two with probability $p^2$. Letting $X$ be the number of nonzero entries in $v_i+v_j$, we have that

$X\sim\operatorname{Ber}(n,1-(1-p)^2)$, and
the number of ones in $v_i+v_j$ is $\operatorname{Ber}(X,\frac{2-2p}{2-p})$.
So, we have
\begin{align*}
\Pr[v_i\text{ and }v_j\text{ unfriendly}]
&=\Pr\left[\operatorname{Ber}\left(X,\frac{2-2p}{2-p}\right)>\frac X2\right]\\
&\geq\Pr\left[\operatorname{Ber}(n,1-(1-p)^2)>\frac n2\right]\cdot\min_{m\geq n/2}\Pr\left[\operatorname{Ber}\left(m,\frac{2-2p}{2-p}\right)>\frac m2\right].
\end{align*}
Note that $\frac{2-2p}{2-p}=\frac{2+6\varepsilon}{4+3\varepsilon}>\frac12$; let it be $\frac1{2(1-\delta)}$ for some $\delta>0$. We now use some Chernoff bounds:
\begin{align*}
\Pr\left[\operatorname{Ber}(n,1-(1-p)^2)>\frac n2\right]
&\geq\Pr\left[\operatorname{Ber}(n,3/4)>\frac n2\right]\geq 1-e^{-n/16}\\
\Pr\left[\operatorname{Ber}\left(m,\frac{2-2p}{2-p}\right)>\frac m2\right]
&=\Pr\left[\operatorname{Ber}\left(m,\frac1{2(1-\delta)}\right)>\frac m2\right]\geq1-e^{-\frac{\delta^2}{4(1-\delta)}m}.
\end{align*}
As a result, letting $\eta=\frac{\delta^2}{4(1-\delta)}<\frac1{10}$, we have
$$\Pr[v_i\text{ and }v_j\text{ unfriendly}]\geq (1-e^{-n/16})\min_{m\geq n/2}(1-e^{-\eta m})\geq 1-2e^{-\eta n/2}.$$
So, as long as $\eta n/2\geq 2\log n$, the probability that any particular pair is not unfriendly will be at most $2/n^2$, and so the probability that there exists a pair which is not unfriendly will be less than $1-1/n$ by the union bound.

Moreover, the probability that there are at most $(2/3-2\varepsilon)n^2$ ones is, by a Chernoff bound,
$$\Pr\left[\operatorname{Ber}\left(n^2,\frac23-\varepsilon\right)<\left(\frac23-2\varepsilon\right)n^2\right]\geq e^{-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{100}n^2}.$$
This is less than $1/n$ as long as $n$ is large enough and $\varepsilon>n^{-1/2}$. So, as long as $\varepsilon>n^{-1/2}$ and $\eta\geq\frac{2\log n}n$, there is an unfriendly $n\times n$ matrix with at least $(2/3-2\varepsilon)n^2$ ones.
What remains is to unfurl our parameters. We have $\delta=\frac{9\varepsilon}{4+12\varepsilon}$ and
$$\eta=\frac{81\varepsilon^2}{(4+12\varepsilon)(4+3\varepsilon)}\geq2\varepsilon^2.$$
So, as long as $\varepsilon\leq(\frac1n\log n)^{1/2}$, we have $\eta\geq\frac{2\log n}n$. We conclude that, for large enough $n$, we can take $\varepsilon=(\frac1n\log n)^{1/2}$. This gives us
$$f(n)\geq\frac23n^2-2n^{3/2}(\log n)^{1/2}-O(1),$$
as desired.

Let $f(n)$ denote the maximum possible number of ones in an $n\times n$ unfriendly matrix. We show that $f(n)\leq \frac{2}{3}n^2+O(n)$.
Consider a binary $n\times n$ matrix $M$ with rows $r_1, \dots, r_n$ and columns $c_1,\dots, c_n$. Let $w(r_i)$ and $w(c_i)$ denote the number of ones in $r_i$ and $c_i$ respectively, and let $w(M)$ be the total number of ones in $M$.  We have $w(M) = \sum_{i=1}^nw(r_i) = \sum_{i=1}^nw(c_i)$. Two rows $r_i$ and $r_j$ are unfriendly if $w(r_i\oplus r_j)>w(r_i\land r_j),$ and since $w(r_i\oplus r_j) = w(r_i)+w(r_j)-2w(r_i\land r_j),$ $r_i$ and $r_j$ are unfriendly iff $w(r_i)+w(r_j)>3w(r_i\land r_j).$ Summing this inequality over all pairs $(i,j)$ with $1 \le i < j \le n$, the left-hand side becomes
$$
\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} (w(r_i) + w(r_j)) = (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n w(r_i) = (n-1)w(M).
$$
Hence, $(n-1)w(M) > 3 \sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} w(r_i\land r_j)$. Now, we can express the right-hand side in terms of columns, by observing that a one in a column with $w(c_k)$ ones is counted $\binom{w(c_k)}{2}$ times. Thus
$$
\sum_{1 \le i < j \le n} w(r_i\land r_j) = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{w(c_k)}{2}.
$$
Hence $(n-1)w(M) > 3 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k(c_k - 1)}{2}$. Since $\sum_{k=1}^nw(c_k) = w(M)$, this inequality simplifies to
$$
 \frac{(2n+1)}{3} w(M)>\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2 .
$$
By Cauchy–Schwarz or Jensen's inequality:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n c_k^2 \ge n\left(\frac{w(M)}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{w(M)^2}{n},
$$
so
$$
\frac{(2n+1)}{3} w(M)>\frac{w(M)^2}{n}.
$$
Rearranging, we obtain
$$
w(M) < \frac{2n^2}{3} + \frac{n}{3}.
$$
Thus, $f(n)\leq \frac{2n^2}{3} + \frac{n}{3} = \frac{2n^2}{3} + O(n)$, as desired.

The computational evidence by RobPratt in their answer seems to suggest that  $\frac{f(n)}{n^2}$ might be a little smaller than $\frac{2}{3}$. The following, argument, though flawed, is a probabilistic heuristic for why we should expect this ratio to not be too much smaller than $\frac{2}{3}$. Construct an $n×n$ matrix by choosing each entry to be $1$ with probability $p=\frac{2}{3}-\varepsilon$​ independently. In expectation, this gives $w(r_i) = pn$, and $w(r_i\land r_j) =p^2n$. Since choosing $p<\frac{2}{3}$ ensures $2p>3p^2$, one could expect all pairs of rows to be unfriendly. Now, of course, to make this rigorous one would need some type of concentration of expectation and the analyze the dependencies of these events.

Very nice answer! I've managed to make your sketch rigorous with a couple applications of Chernoff bounds. But all the ideas are in your answer.

Thank you! And thank you for writing it up in detail :)

For fixed $n$, you can solve the problem via integer linear programming.  The idea is to find a maximum-weight independent set of cardinality $n$ in a graph defined as follows.  Let $N=\{0,\dots,2^n-1\}$ be the set of nodes (one per possible row, interpreted as a binary expansion).  Let $w_i$ be the Hamming weight of $i\in N$.  Let $$E = \left\{i\in N, j\in N: i < j \text{ and } w_{i \oplus j} \le w_{i \land j} \right\}$$ be the set of (conflict) edges.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $$\sum_{i\in N} w_i x_i$$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
x_i + x_j &\le 1 &&\text{for $(i,j)\in E$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{i\in N} x_i &= n \tag2\label2 \\
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} prevents selecting both $i$ and $j$.  Constraint \eqref{2} selects exactly $n$ nodes.
A weaker but smaller formulation might scale better.  Explicitly, let $$N_i = \{j\in N: (i,j)\in E \lor (j,i)\in E\}$$ be the neighbors of node $i$.  Then replace \eqref{1} with
$$\sum_{j\in N_i} x_j \le \min(|N_i|,n)(1-x_i) \quad \text{for $i\in N$} \tag3\label3$$
This big-M constraint enforces $x_i=1 \implies x_j=0$ for all $j\in N_i$.
Yet another approach is to replace \eqref{1} with
$$\sum_{j\in N \setminus (N_i \cup \{i\})} x_j \ge (n-1)x_i \quad \text{for $i\in N$} \tag4\label4$$
This big-M constraint enforces $x_i=1 \implies x_j=1$ for at least (hence exactly) $n-1$ non-neighbors of $i$.
Here are optimal values for small $n$:
\begin{matrix}
n & \max \\
\hline
1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 \\
3 & 6 \\
4 & 9 \\
5 & 13 \\
6 & 21 \\
7 & 28 \\
8 & 40 \\
9 & 48 \\
10 & 58 \\
11 & 72
\end{matrix}
For example, an optimal solution for $n=3$ is $x_3=x_5=x_6=1$, yielding matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
with total weight $w_3 + w_5 + w_6 = 2 + 2 + 2 = 6$.

Even getting the answer for $n=10$ seems hard this way. Which MIP tool are you using?

@Simd I use SAS.

Would finding the max weight clique on the complement graph be faster? I tried that way but couldn't find how to use the cliquer-algorithm with vertex weights in Sage so I just iterated over all the $n$-cliques and gathered a whole polynomial enumerating the counts (and its degree was the solution).

Yes, clique in the complement is equivalent to independent set in the original.

How long did $n=10$ take? It tooks  a few minutes using ortools. $n=12$ has been running for hours though.

A couple minutes, but the big-M formulation I just added to my answer took 17 seconds.

Do you get 72 and 90 for $n = 11, 12$?

Yes, $72$ is optimal for $n=11$.  For $n=12$, the best I have found so far is $90$.
